# How to observe open loop characteristics with loading conditions?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering, transfer-function, feedback-loop

I have derived transfer function of a dc motor (armature controlled). Its input is armature voltage and output is speed of motor in rad/s. How do I observe open loop characteristics with an external load in MATLAB. Max motor speed is 4000rpm and power is 0.289 hp. The transfer function is given below:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE. If you are a new visitor, please visit the [tour] page. A suggestion: please copy and paste code instead of screenshots. Please include relevant details such as a diagram, description of the variables used, the differential equations used to derive the above transfer function. With the differential equations included in the question, it will be easy to point out where the load term appears.